# Linux create symlink on slow drive to tmpfs

Tags: linux, symlink, tmpfs

My application creates cache for read/write inside my OS drive, which is slow, so I have mounted tmpfs and created a directory inside it. Then I created a symlink at the path on the slow drive where the caches are created, pointing at the tmpfs directory.

I want to know if my app does a lot of read/write using the symlink, is it going to affect tmpfs or OS drive performance?

My partitions are:

```
tmpfs /cache/dp/
/dev/sda3 /  <-- subdir /this/is/location
```

I created the symlink with:

```
ln -s /cache/dp /this/is/location
```

Comment: Symlinks only record the name of their target, nothing else. Are you just using the tmpfs as a cache of names or hoping for more?

Comment: @PhilipCouling My app will do heavy read/write inside the symlink directory because I cannot change paths inside my app. I want to know if it will still use my slow OS disk I/O with same old performance or is it going to use tmpfs I/O and gives faster result?

Comment: Could you [edit] in 1) the command used to create the link, and 2) the paths of the two *mount points* of the system drive & tmpfs?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I haved edited my question

Comment: Also, how about if I mount /this/is/location  to tmpfs rather than symlinking? Is this a better solution? Or can I use bind mount /this/is/location  to  tmpfs /cache/dp  directory?